# sybase update trigger check

Tags: triggers, sql-update, duplicates, sybase

In Sybase i have main table called test and audit table test_a. To update audit table i created triggers insert,update and delete. But the issue is when i do an update query with same data that is existing with no changes the update trigger gets fire and records in the audit table for every update which is creating duplication. I want to stop update trigger to fire when no changes are made when using update query.It should trigger only when new row is inserted but not existing.

my table has

```
test : ID | NAME | DESC
test_a : UPDATED_BY|DATE|ID|NAME|DESC
```

can you suggest how to stop trigger firing when no new changes are updated in the query.

Thank you.

Comment: Then remove the `update` trigger and only use an `insert` trigger.

Comment: I know we can replace insert instead of update but i want in update trigger  to check if the value is new or old and if its new it updates and if old it shouldn't update.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stop an update trigger from firing - an UPDATE statement will always fire it. But you can compare the contents of the 'inserted' and 'deleted' table to determine whether any values were indeed updated. If not, then don't modify the audit table.